# Boot error (PREEMPT ARM) and screen freeze

Tags: boot, kernel

I had used and tested my RPi B+ almost 2 months ago, with different TVs (via HDMI and AV), and it worked without any problem.

Today, I wanted to test my RPi B+ again (after 2 months of not using it) with a brand new Samsung TV via HDMI.

I get the following error during boot:

```
[    1.794149] Internal error: Oops - undefined instruction: 0 [#1] PREEMPT ARM
[    1.801348] Modules linked in
[    1.804467] CPU: 0 PID: 1713401189 Comm: ed
[    1.804467]  Not tainted 3.12.28+ #709
```

When I power on the RPi B+, the logo appear on TV, but then those errors come and it freezes.
Cycling the power solves the problem sometimes and it boots successfully.
But that error (and screen freeze) happens in 50% of boot times.

What shall I do !?

Comment: Try do diagnose the problem.  Does it still work with the earlier working displays?

Answer (score -4):

Make sure your SD card is inserted and/or not damaged

Comment: While this is generally good advise, I fail to see what makes you think a problem with the SD card is the origin of this particular problem.